# Build Error with ng-packagr and material 2.0.0-beta.12

Tags: angular, angular-material, ng-packagr

I am receiving a build error when I try to run ng-packagr with material: 2.0.0-beta.12 as a dependency. It's looking for `node_modules/@angular/packages/material` which the packages folder doesn't exist in node_modules so I get `ENOENT: no such file or directory open`.

I have submitted this to the material and ng-packagr issue trackers but it could very well be something I'm doing locally. I started a new project here [material-issue-project](https://github.com/nmrichards/material-issue-project) and the only thing it does is import one module (MatIconModule) from material library.

Has anyone else had this issue? Might not be too many people out there using ng-packagr with material-beta.12 but any thoughts or tips would be greatly appreciated.

I'm not really sure how to explain it since I don't understand what's happening but here is the material [issue](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/7681) and the ng-packagr [issue](https://github.com/dherges/ng-packagr/issues/172). I'm sure there's a need for clarification so just let me know. I also attached a screenshot of the error I'm receiving.

[image: Picture of error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears there is a problem with the sourcemaps in material beta.12. Look at [this comment](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/7681#issuecomment-335482131) to set material as an external peer dependency for the current workaround.